# What is efficient- record in class or n fields

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have class with 8 byte fields. I can put them in record and put record in 1 class field (record is packed and efficient).

I have 100000 objects of this class. So need efficient variant- which is efficient, less memory: byte fields or record field?

It's FPC 2.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While nobody of FPC gurus have no time to answer, lets explore this question. Here is some code for this:

```
program Project1;

type
    TByteArray = packed array[Low(Word)..High(Word)] of Byte;
    PByteArray = ^TByteArray;

    TMyRec = packed record
        f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8: Byte;
    end;

    { TMyClass1 }

    TMyClass1 = class
        mark1: Byte;
        f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8: Byte;
        mark2: Byte;
        r: TMyRec;
        mark3: Byte;
        constructor Create;
        procedure ShowMe; // Dump of the object's data
    end;

{ TMyClass1 }

constructor TMyClass1.Create;
begin
    mark1 := 66;
    mark2 := 77;
    mark3 := 88;
end;

procedure TMyClass1.ShowMe;
var
    data: PByteArray;
    i: Word;
begin
    data := Pointer(Self);
    for i := 0 to 15 + 4 + 3 do // 4 - some unknown data at the beginning of the class, 3 - marks
        Writeln(data^[i]);
end;

var
    test: TMyClass1;
begin
    test := TMyClass1.Create;
    try
        test.ShowMe;
        Readln;
    finally
        test.Free;
    end;
end.
```

And output is:

```
0
192
64
0
66 <- Data starts, simple fields
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
77 <- Second data portion, record
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
88 <- Data ends
```

As we can see in both cases 8 fields takes 8 bytes.

Good luck.

Comment: There was no need for demo. Records are **value types**, classes are **reference types**. That's also why i always though that the primitive TList in the RTL or the FCL should be a record and then only wrapped as a class with virtual methods and the all the slow stuff.

Comment: @Nestedtype Just read the question again: "_which is efficient, less memory: byte fields or record field?_ (both in the class)" But I absolutely agree with you: simpler types produces more efficient code :)

Comment: Yes, i miss _both in class_. I think that in another answer someone was not that sure that the memory layout would be exactly the same, sorry maybe it was not yours.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you think that packing is really important, simply declare the class packed:

```
TMyClass1 = packed class
    mark1: Byte;
    f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8: Byte;
    mark2: Byte;
    r: TMyRec;
    mark3: Byte;
    constructor Create;
    procedure ShowMe; // Dump of the object's data
end;
```

Classes will always have some overhead, but that is not necessarily the packing of the fields, but hidden administration. And over time that overhead has gotten bigger.

But 100000 records is peanuts. If you waste a few bytes, it is like 10MB or so, a fraction of the memory of the cheapest PC available nowadays.